# How to initialize only parts of a two dimensional array?

Tags: java

I don't understand why this snippet doesn't work:

```
arraySize = input.nextInt();
int [][] twoD = new int [arraySize][arraySize];
twoD = { {1},{2} }; //Error occurs here. The above code works but if I try to initialize it partly it doesn't work? Why's that, how is my syntax wrong?
```

Comment: The `{ ... }` syntax is an initializer.  You can't initialize something that's already initialized.

Comment: Try `twoD[0][0] = 1; twoD[1][0] = 2;` and hope that user didn't enter an array size of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax isn't legal there (the omission of type is syntatic sugar for declaration). You **can do**

```
twoD = new int[][] { {1},{2} };
```

But `twoD` will be fully initialized with two arrays of length `1` (and arrays have a fixed length).

Comment: Well another question just popped in my mind but, you answered this question. For that, thanks.